# How to do Comma Separted Printing of a list on python

Tags: python

What would be the cleanest way to do comma separated printing on python for a list.

```
I have list: [1,2,3,4]

I need: "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Comment: `print(','.join([1,2,3,4,...]))`

Comment: You should put what do you try before ask something that with a simple search on google you can find the answer. And this is probably answered before.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque You can only [use join with sequences of strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `map` to apply `str` method to all the items to convert `int` to `str` and then use `join` method to concatenate the list:

[string.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join)

> Concatenate a list or tuple of words with intervening occurrences of
>   sep.

```
a=[1,2,3,4]

print ",".join(map(str,a))
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Some explanation would help

Answer (score 1):

The only unusual part is the `...`, which `str` and `repr` both unfortunately turn into `'Ellipsis'`. The other answers don't handle it correctly, but this one does:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
>>> print(', '.join('...' if x is ... else str(x) for x in a))
1, 2, 3, 4, ...
```

Edit: This is for the original question, before it was changed (though it still works).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something on this line.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5] 
m = map(str, mylist) # map function to convert each item in the list to a string 
j = ', '.join(m) # join to combine those strings with ', '
print (j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually have `...` and don't actually want to print the quotes:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(*a, sep=', ')
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Or less clean:

```
>>> print(str(a)[1:-1])
1, 2, 3, 4
```